# Is it possible to use Moz2D graphics API for drawing in a desktop application?

Tags: c++, firefox, graphics, 2d

Moz2D is the new backend for Firefox, to which it's currently switching from Cairo. One of Moz2D's benefits over Cairo is that it makes rendering work quicker in Firefox.
Here is basic info on Moz2D https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/GFX/Moz2D

So, is it possible to use Moz2D outside of Firefox to draw to, for example, SDK window?

If yes, could you please provide some basic guidelines for doing that? The Moz2D documentation in its current state is very poor.

Comment: You should probably ask the [`Moz2D`](http://hg.mozilla.org/users/bschouten_mozilla.com/moz2d/) people about this directly, via email or in [IRC](https://wiki.mozilla.org/IRC)...

Answer (score 2):

from mozilla irc's #gfx:

```
<wafje> is Moz2D/Azure available as an API outside of Firefox, or is it intended to be just for Firefox?
<milan> wafje: it is usable outside the Firefox, at least in that it builds "standalone", but I'm not aware of anybody actually using it in production
  <Bas> milan: I guess Servo, technically.
<milan> Bas: right, and the standalone Skia tests; are they actually running those?
  <Bas> milan: Skia is, or should be.. or do you mean the stand-alone Moz2D tests?
<milan> Bas: probably both :)
  <Bas> milan: To the best of my knowledge neither
```